# Is there a plot twist in Alien: Covenant?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

In **[Alien: Covenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien:_Covenant)** Walter and David fight during a scene near the end. However, the editing cuts off their fight and we never see how it ends. At the end of the film, Michael Fassbender's character shows sympathy and fascination for the Alien species, and regurgitates eggs to keep them safe inside the ship.

Which led me to wonder this...

***Did David actually kill Walter, then cut off his hand to pretend to be Walter during the end scenes?***

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is David who is aboard the ship  Covenant. David has copied itself to the physical body of Walter.

This is clear because as Walter (as we are believed at the time) puts Daniels to sleep in her pod, she asks Walter if he will help her realize her dream of building a log cabin on their new homeworld, which she has confided with walter earlier during a private conversation. But now Walter doesn't seems to understand this, which makes it clear to her and audiences that it is NOT Walter but indeed David.

**Just a trivia:** Towards end of movie, while Daniels and Walter speak, A wind blows Walter's hood to his head, which is a foreshadowing of who he really is.

(David's initial appearance in the movie was in a hooded figure.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! That was SO unclear for me at time of viewing...

Comment: @TommyPKeane Daniels stabs David in the chin with her nail necklace. We know that the Walter model heals itself, and says "There have been a few upgrades" which indicates that the David model can't quickly heal. After the the flight back to Covenant, we see "Walter" helping Daniels and Tennesse eject the alien out of the cargo bay. After the ejection we see Walter lean back, and we catch a brief glimpse under his chin where he was stabbed, no nail wound. This indicates David uploaded his personality into the body of Waler.

Comment: @TommyTommy - maybe because part of a movie experience is having the audience actually think, figure things out that are not shown. It's not a plot hole if something isn't shown, if it's a pedantic, ordinary thing. Computers and computer-based equipment being able to upload and download information isn't some kind of novel concept that would need to be shown to be believable, as my ability to transfer these words from my keyboard to the stackexchange server to your browser demonstrates.

Comment: @BenPlont But then how come David has visible scars on his face, that Daniels actually helped him stitch? If David copied himself over into Walters's body, would not the scars have healed?